# Como utilizar um módulo no AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-directives

Tenho o seguinte código em AngularJS mas estou com o erro:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthenticationProvider <-
>   Authentication

Meu código é o seguinte:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, Authentication) {
    var usuario = { login : 'teste', senha : 'senha123'};
    $scope.usuario = Authentication.autenticar(usuario);
});
```

**authentication.js**

```
angular.module('api.Authentication', [
    'ngResource'
])
.factory('Authentication', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(endpoint + 'users/authentications', {}, {
        autenticar: { method: 'POST' }
    });
}]);
```

O que está faltando? Porque ele não identifica a factory `Authentication`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na parte

```javascript
 angular.module('app')
.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, Authentication) {
    var usuario = { login : 'teste', senha : 'senha123'};
    $scope.usuario = Authentication.autenticar(usuario);
});
```

troque para

```javascript
angular.module('app', ["api.Authentication"] )
.controller('HomeController', [
    "$scope",
    "Authentication",
    function ($scope, Authentication) {
        var usuario = { login : 'teste', senha : 'senha123'};
        $scope.usuario = Authentication.autenticar(usuario);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Falta importar o módulo `api.Authentication` no arquivo `app.js`

```js
angular.module('app', [
   'api.Authentication'  
])
...
```

Assim o módulo fica disponível para ser utilizado.